# How to determine when a value is stabilized

Tags: vba

I am trying to find a way to determine when a value is stabilized in excel. In this case, temperature. I have a set of time-series data, TIMESTAMP and TEMPERATURE. at T=0, the temperature begins to rise at a rapid rate. When the setpoint temperature is approached, the rate of rise decreases, until finally, it stabilizes around the setpoint. The temperature tends to overshoot and undershoot the setpoint by several degrees before stabilization.

How can I have excel figure out when the temperature is "Stable" around the setpoint? For example, Delta T (SP-PV) <= 2. (Delta T is difference between Set Point SP and Process Variable PV)

I was thinking possibly using a time variable to determine a data set size (i.e. 5 minutes) and see if the average Delta T within that time is <= 2.

I do not know how to get excel to search through the whole series effectively though.

Answer (score 0):

If you only look at the difference between the setpoint and the value at some time 0, you may mistake a crossing as a "stabilized" point. You need to examine both the estimated rate of change (Tn - Tn-1)/dt and the current value.

Stability is going to be a combination of "how fast is my signal still changing" and "how close am I". It isn't uncommon in real systems for there to be a fixed offset (steady state error) between a setpoint and a measurement with no change happening in the signal over time. This is typically corrected by an integrative term in the control system.

Comment: Mike, good points. So really then, I can examine the rate of change over a series of data points and figure out if the temperature is stable that way, and use the delta T to see if it is close enough to the setpoint to say it is there.